# Codeigniter DB class vs prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo, mysqli

Hi I was wondering if using Codeigniters active record class is equivalent to using prepared statements in terms of security issues?

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

vs.

```
 $data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CI doesn’t support prepared statements, it does support Query Bindings though. Both query bindings and prepared statements prevent sql injection. But I prefers AR because the ease of use. Also it makes the query more readable.

You can check this [link](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/105112/#528929) for more details.

And check the CI Query Binding from this [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

to directly answer the question. yes.

both statements are escaped which provides security from injection attacks.
CodeIgniter db insert method does the escaping for you, and a php prepared statement includes escaping by nature.

see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) info on php prepared statements.

otherwise in terms of speed, how they run etc, the two statements are not equivalent.

Hussain has covered the rest.